# Need query to list rows where two columns are relatively the same with caveat in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Most compare two or more columns for the same value between two tables. I need to compare two columns in a table where relative to another column with 3 owner values used. This will be 3 different first names.

I have seen table compares, but this is in one table and data is separated already by a column value. The table is thousands of rows. Owner column is only three different names.

So Joe, Sam and Jim have rows of names.  When any of these two people have a common first and last name listed in the row, they will be listed as output with other column data like location and zip. So if Joe and Sam have two common names, the output will list:

```
Owner,firstname,lastname,location,zip

Joe,Bob,Smith,Dallas,37377

Sam,Bob,Smith,Dallas,37377
```

Jim had no `Bob,Smith,Dallas,37377` so it is not listed in the group with Joe and Sam.  In summation, the results will be a few hundred lines of these 3 owners grouped where a common name is found.  I will need to use percentages in the query in case some one uses Bobby or Smiths. Therefore a name like Smithson will show up but I will adjust.

I had this all typed out and the page sees it as code so I apologize I had to abbreviate.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward thing to use is a self-join, though an EXISTS may be quicker.

First, the self-join:

```
--note DISTINCT here because if Joe, Bob, and Sam all have records with the name we don't want duplicates
select DISTINCT f.owner, f.firstname, f.lastname, f.location, f.zip
from tablename f
join tablename s on f.firstname = s.firstname and f.lastname = s.lastname and f.owner <> s.owner
```

Then, with an EXISTS:

```
select f.owner, f.firstname, f.lastname, f.location, f.zip
from tablename f
WHERE EXISTS(select 1 from tablename s WHERE s.firstname = f.firstname and s.lastname = f.lastname and s.owner <> f.owner)
```

Of course, if instead of equality you want 'Smith' and 'smithson' to match, you can replace the equality comparison with something like: `(f.firstname ilike (s.firstname||'%') OR s.firstname ilike (f.firstname||'%'))` you can use that (or any other comparison)